# How to modify the Imagenet Caffe Model?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I would like to modify the ImageNet caffe model as described bellow:

> As the input channel number for temporal nets is different from that
>   of spatial nets (20 vs. 3), we average the ImageNet model filters of
>   first layer across the channel, and then copy the average results 20
>   times as the initialization of temporal nets.

My question is how can I achive the above results? How can I open the caffe model to be able to do those changes to it?

I read the net surgery tutorial but it doesn't cover the procedure needed.

Thank you for your assistance!

AMayer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Net Surgery tutorial](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) should give you the basics you need to cover this. But let me explain the steps you need to do in more detail:

1. Prepare the `.prototxt` network architectures: You need two files: the existing ImageNet `.prototxt` file, and your new temporal network architecture. You should make all layers *except* the first convolutional layers identical in both networks, including the names of the layers. That way, you can use the ImageNet `.caffemodel` file to initialize the weights automatically.

   As the first conv layer has a different size, you have to give it a different name in your `.prototxt` file than it has in the ImageNet file. Otherwise, Caffe will try to initialize this layer with the existing weights too, which will fail as they have different shapes. (This is what happens in the edit to your question.) Just name it e.g. `conv1b` and change all references to that layer accordingly.
2. Load the ImageNet network for testing, so you can extract the parameters from the model file:

   ```
   net = caffe.Net('imagenet.prototxt', 'imagenet.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
   ```
3. Extract the weights from this loaded model.

   ```
   conv_1_weights = old_net.params['conv1'][0].data
   conv_1_biases = old_net.params['conv1'][1].data
   ```
4. Average the weights across the channels:

   ```
   conv_av_weights = np.mean(conv_1_weights, axis=1, keepdims=True)
   ```
5. Load your new network together with the old `.caffemodel` file, as all layers except for the first layer directly use the weights from ImageNet:

   ```
   new_net = caffe.Net('new_network.prototxt', 'imagenet.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
   ```
6. Assign your calculated average weights to the new network

   ```
   new_net.params['conv1b'][0].data[...] = conv_av_weights
   new_net.params['conv1b'][1].data[...] = conv_1_biases
   ```
7. Save your weights to a new `.caffemodel` file:

   ```
   new_net.save('new_weights.caffemodel')
   ```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I'm testing it right now. I will update you shortly about how it went. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I've enounter an error. I have updated the main post with the code that I used based on your suggestion for better view of the problem. Later I will delete the code to not confuse the new readers. What I did wrong there? Thank you!

Comment: I've managed to get passed that error, but enountered another one. I've updated the main post. Thank you!

Comment: @AMayer I've edited my answer (step 1, and the code in step 6) to describe how to fix the error. Please let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: It fixed the prev error, but now I get the following error:
 new_net.params['conv1b'][0].data[...] = conv_av_weights
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96,11,11) into shape (96,20,11,11)

Comment: Oops, seems like we lost an axis on the way ;) Please see the edited step 4.

Comment: It fixed it, but there's one more. Here is the error:  new_net.params['conv1b'][1].data = conv_1_biases 
AttributeError: can't set attribute. Thank you! I truly appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Can you try adding `[...]` to after `data`, as shown in step 6? I forgot that before and added it in the last edit. Hope it works now :)

Comment: what does the  [...] mean?

Comment: With `[...]` you modify the `data` in-place, i.e. copies the data to the place where `data` points now. Without the `[...]` it would change the reference to point to `conv_av_weights`  instead of copying the data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42191121/4221706) for more details.