# What does "three dots" in Python mean when indexing what looks like a number?

Tags: python, numpy, iterator

What is the meaning of `x[...]` below?

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    x[...] = 2 * x
```

Comment: That's not a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Python Ellipsis object do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do)

Comment: Must fun way to understand this is James Powell's talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65_-6kEAq58

Answer (score 103):

While the proposed duplicate [What does the Python Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do) answers the question in a general `python` context, its use in an `nditer` loop requires, I think, added information.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values

> Regular assignment in Python simply changes a reference in the local or global variable dictionary instead of modifying an existing variable in place. This means that simply assigning to x will not place the value into the element of the array, but rather switch x from being an array element reference to being a reference to the value you assigned. To actually modify the element of the array, x should be indexed with the ellipsis.

That section includes your code example.

So in my words, the `x[...] = ...` modifies `x` in-place;  `x = ...` would have broken the link to the `nditer` variable, and not changed it.  It's like `x[:] = ...` but works with arrays of any dimension (including 0d).  In this context `x` isn't just a number, it's an array.

Perhaps the closest thing to this `nditer` iteration, without `nditer` is:

```
In [667]: for i, x in np.ndenumerate(a):
     ...:     print(i, x)
     ...:     a[i] = 2 * x
     ...:     
(0, 0) 0
(0, 1) 1
...
(1, 2) 5
In [668]: a
Out[668]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 6,  8, 10]])
```

Notice that I had to index and modify `a[i]` directly.  I could not have used, `x = 2*x`.  In this iteration `x` is a scalar, and thus not mutable

```
In [669]: for i,x in np.ndenumerate(a):
     ...:     x[...] = 2 * x
  ...
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object does not support item assignment
```

But in the `nditer` case `x` is a 0d array, and mutable.

```
In [671]: for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
     ...:     print(x, type(x), x.shape)
     ...:     x[...] = 2 * x
     ...:     
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> ()
4 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> ()
...
```

And because it is 0d, `x[:]` cannot be used instead of `x[...]`

```
----> 3     x[:] = 2 * x
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

A simpler array iteration might also give insight:

```
In [675]: for x in a:
     ...:     print(x, x.shape)
     ...:     x[:] = 2 * x
     ...:     
[ 0  8 16] (3,)
[24 32 40] (3,)
```

this iterates on the rows (1st dim) of `a`.  `x` is then a 1d array, and can be modified with either `x[:]=...` or `x[...]=...`.

And if I add the `external_loop` flag from the next [section](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#using-an-external-loop), `x` is now a 1d array, and `x[:] =` would work.  But `x[...] =` still works and is more general.  `x[...]` is used all the other `nditer` examples.

```
In [677]: for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite'], flags=['external_loop']):
     ...:     print(x, type(x), x.shape)
     ...:     x[...] = 2 * x
[ 0 16 32 48 64 80] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (6,)
```

Compare this simple row iteration (on a 2d array):

```
In [675]: for x in a:
     ...:     print(x, x.shape)
     ...:     x[:] = 2 * x
     ...:     
[ 0  8 16] (3,)
[24 32 40] (3,)
```

this iterates on the rows (1st dim) of `a`.  `x` is then a 1d array, and can be modified with either `x[:] = ...` or `x[...] = ...`.

Read and experiment with this `nditer` page all the way through to the end.  By itself, `nditer` is not that useful in `python`.  It does not speed up iteration - not until you port your code to [`cython`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#putting-the-inner-loop-in-cython).`np.ndindex` is one of the few non-compiled `numpy` functions that uses `nditer`.

Comment: Note that things like x[1,:,...] are also an allowed syntax. Left for future reference.

Answer (score 73):

The ellipsis `...` means `as many : as needed`.

For people who don't have time, here is a simple example:

```
In [64]: X = np.reshape(np.arange(9), (3,3))

In [67]: Y = np.reshape(np.arange(2*3*4), (2,3,4))

In [70]: X
Out[70]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [71]: X[:,0]
Out[71]: array([0, 3, 6])

In [72]: X[...,0]
Out[72]: array([0, 3, 6])

In [73]: Y
Out[73]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

In [74]: Y[:,0]
Out[74]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [75]: Y[...,0]
Out[75]:
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [12, 16, 20]])

In [76]: X[0,...,0]
Out[76]: array(0)

In [77]: Y[0,...,0]
Out[77]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

This makes it easy to manipulate only one dimension at a time.

One thing - You can have only one ellipsis in any given indexing expression, or your expression would be ambiguous about how many `:` should be put in each.

Comment: You write `as many : as needed`, but in `Y[...,0]`, how many are *needed*? None, I would argue. Would `as many : as *possible*` be more correct?

Answer (score 6):

I believe a very good parallel (that most people are maybe used to) is to think that way:

```py
import numpy as np

random_array = np.random.rand(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

In such case, `[:, :, :, 0] and [..., 0]` are the same.

You can use to analyse only an specific dimension, say you have a batch of 50 128x128 RGB image (50, 3, 128, 128), if you want to slice a piece of it in every image at every color channel, you could either do `image[:,:,50:70, 20:80] or image[...,50:70,20:80]`

Just be aware that you can't use it more than once in the statement like `[...,0,...]` is invalid.