# Python can't open file "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, compiler-errors

```
def main():
    fh = open('lines.txt')
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Directory files

[image]

I am on `for-working.py` file, and am trying to access the `lines.txt` file within the same working directory. But I get error

> No such file or directory: 'lines.txt'

Does python need to have an absolute path when opening files?

why doesn't this relative path work here?

Running python 3.6

**EDIT ^1** I'm running visualstudio code with the python package extension by Don Jayamanne, and "Code Runner" package to compile/execute python code

**EDIT ^2** Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\www\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT(1)\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT\Exercise Files\07 Loops\for-working.py", line 11, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "c:\www\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT(1)\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT\Exercise Files\07 Loops\for-working.py", line 7, in main
    fh = open('lines.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lines.txt'
```

**EDIT ^3** checking sys.path

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

produces this information:

```
['c:\\www\\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT(1)\\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT\\Exercise Files\\07 Loops', 
'C:\\Users\\Kagerjay\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Kagerjay\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Kagerjay\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Kagerjay\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36', 'C:\\Users\\Kagerjay\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**EDIT ^4** checking os.getcwd()

Running

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Produces

```
c:\www\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT(1)\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT\Exercise Files
```

**Well its definitely not in the right subdirectory (needs to `cd 07 loops` folder, that narrows the issue down**

**EDIT ^5** what is in lines.txt file

My lines.txt file i am opening looks like this. No extra whitespace or anything at start

```
01 This is a line of text
02 This is a line of text
03 This is a line of text
04 This is a line of text
05 This is a line of text
```

**IN SUMMARY**

Visual studio code's Code runner extension needs to be tweaked slightly to open files within a subdirectory so any of the below answers would provide a more robust solution to be independent of any extension / dependencies with the IDE

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Is most useful for diagnosing problem to the current directory python interpreter sees

Comment: Try to use `fh = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'lines.txt'))`

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Change `fh = open('lines.txt')` to `fh = open('lines.txt', 'r')`

Comment: @GreenSaber `'r'` is the default argument and can be omitted.

Comment: none of these solutions work some reason

Comment: i dumped some more information on post hopefully this helps out?

Comment: What do you see when you `import sys; print (sys.path)`

Comment: @keatinge when running on cmd `sys.path` I get this error "The term 'sys.path' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet......" and then "object not found:(sys.path:string)[], commandnotfoundException"

Comment: @Kagerjay it's python code, put it in that same file

Comment: @Keatinge I added information when i ran a python program with only `import sys` and `sys.path` only in post

Comment: It's not `sys.path` what is relevant in this case, but `os.getcwd()`. Check the output of `import os; print(os.getcwd())`. If it is not the full path to the folder "07 Loops" then the Python interpreter is running from a different directory. Also, this is silly but sometimes happens, make sure the file "lines.txt" doesn't have any extra whitespace at the beginning or end of its name or something like that.

Comment: @jdhesa I edited my post, it definitely isn't in the right subdirectory, how would I fix this? Lines.txt doesn't have any whitespace in beginning

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the directory of the file, and join it with the file you want to open:

```
def main():
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    lines = os.path.join(dir_path, "lines.txt")
    fh = open(lines)
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: I did what you suggested here but I don't know what i'm doing wrong here, see image http://i.imgur.com/SJIQTib.png

Comment: No, replace your call to `open` with those 3 lines.  yours becomes `fh = open(lines)`

Comment: thanks this helps out a lot. What does the `...` do anyhow? (i copied your first solution into my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
def main():
    fh = open('lines.txt')
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # get's the path of the script
    os.chdir(curr_dir)  # changes the current path to the path of the script
    main()
```

Comment: this works but I feel like that's alot of excessive code though, its not really the pythonic way of doing things

Comment: I don't think this is a great solution.  You shouldn't need to change the working directory of the process just to open a file.  This may have unneeded side effects for other parts of the process.  See my answer for a more robust solution, which is to determine the absolute path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same trouble today. The solution was outside the code, in the environment.

[Shows the picture of VSCode settings editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2e2R.png)

Command prompt in VSCode opens with the directory where VSCode executable is placed. When you execute the code, Python is searching for the file in the location where the VSCode executable is located.

This setting can be changed to the directory that you are working in(shown in figure). So when you are running the code in yourprog.py file, the interpretor is started in your working directory.

Then the VScode runner will do the way you are thinking.

Answer (score -1):

okay summary of working solutions to my problem from others not mentioned in post

Direct absolute path manually

```
def main():
    fh = open('lines.txt')
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    curr_dir = 'c:\\www\\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT(1)\\Ex_Files_Python_3_EssT\\Exercise Files\\07 Loops'
    os.chdir(curr_dir)
    main()
```

I commented out unnecessary parts `...` and `open(lines` at beginning

Below solution is very good for lazy implementation tests (e.g. copy-paste template), since all the absolute path correction code is up top seperated from everything else **(my preferred solution)**

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
lines = os.path.join(dir_path, "lines.txt")
# open(lines)
# ...

def main():
    fh = open(lines)
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Most robust solution would be this one below, since its self-contained only in the function definition when main() gets called. Original answer didn't include the `import os` so I included it here

```
def main():
    import os
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    lines = os.path.join(dir_path, "lines.txt")
    fh = open(lines)
    for line in fh.readlines():
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: See my edited answer.  The ellipsis (...) was just meant to be a placeholder for your code, not actual code.

Comment: that's strange it still runs though even with `...` does the python interpreter ignore it like comments?

Comment: it says the `...` is an eillpisis object / placeholder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190783/what-does-three-dots-in-python-mean-when-indexing-what-looks-like-a-number