# problem with loading images with pygame/python

Tags: python-3.x

the imgs won't load from a subfolder.  Whats weird is that even when the images are right beside the main code in the main folder it still does not work

```
background = pygame.image.load("img/road.png").convert()

guy = pygame.image.load("img/idle.png").convert()
guy.set_colorkey(WHITE)

zombie = pygame.image.load("img/zombie.png").convert()
zombie.set_colorkey(GREEN)
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:/Users/tcric/Documents/code/game_jam.py", line 41, in <module> background = pygame.image.load("img/road.png").convert() 
pygame.error: Couldn't open img/road.png
```

Comment: Any error messages? (Add them to the question.)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/tcric/Documents/code/game_jam.py", line 41, in <module>
    background = pygame.image.load("img/road.png").convert()
pygame.error: Couldn't open img/road.png

Comment: You run the program in a folder that does not have `"img/road.png"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python can't open file "No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636411/python-cant-open-file-no-such-file-or-directory)