# Python: most efficient way to mirror an image along its vertical axis

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I have a lot of images that I will need to flip (on the fly) and so am looking for the fastest way possible to do this using Python.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I have image files on disk and have tried to ways, shown in my own answer below, but these start with Numpy arrays and so may not be optimal. Are there better ways?

Comment: How are the images stored? As a list of arrays or one big array?

Comment: Stored as single `.jpg` files. For my own attempts below I read them into a numpy array once at the beginning, using `matplotlib.image.imread()`

Comment: Let me put it another way. You have `images` in your answer post. So, is `images` an array or a list?

Comment: Ah ok - three images were in a single numpy array. I have added the `shape` to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `slicing` to flip the second last axis to get equivalent flipped view into the input array of images, as such won't be creating any new data in memory and hence an efficient one, like so -

```
images[...,::-1,:]
```

If you still need to make a copy, use `.copy` there, which would still be more efficient than `np.fliplr` and noticeable with small/decent sized arrays.

Runtime test -

It seems NumPy is the winner, so I will test it out against that one.

```
In [64]: images = np.random.randint(0,255,(3,200,400,3))

In [65]: out1 = np.array([np.fliplr(images[i]) for i in range(3)])

In [66]: out2 = images[...,::-1,:]

In [67]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[67]: True

In [68]: %timeit np.array([np.fliplr(images[i]) for i in range(3)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 ms per loop

In [69]: %timeit images[...,::-1,:]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 259 ns per loop # virtually free
```

If you need copy -

```
In [76]: images = np.random.randint(0,255,(3,10,10,3))

In [77]: %timeit np.array([np.fliplr(images[i]) for i in range(3)])
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.76 µs per loop

In [78]: %timeit images[...,::-1,:].copy()
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.23 µs per loop

In [79]: images = np.random.randint(0,255,(3,100,100,3))

In [80]: %timeit np.array([np.fliplr(images[i]) for i in range(3)])
10000 loops, best of 3: 159 µs per loop

In [81]: %timeit images[...,::-1,:].copy()
10000 loops, best of 3: 152 µs per loop
```

Comment: That's great! I tested it too... `%timeit -r 10 -n 100000
images[...,::-1,:]`.  369 ns ± 125 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each). For others like me not familiar with the three dots (_Ellipsis_ object), here are a few hints: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190783/what-does-three-dots-in-python-mean-when-indexing-what-looks-like-a-number)

Comment: Thanks for the additional `copy` info. Also, accepted, as I don't believe we can beat _for free_! :)

Comment: Also worth looking at the [implementation of fliplr](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L82) to see that it's just a shorthand for slicing anyway, with extra checks

Answer (score 6):

Here are two ways, using:

1. OpenCV   `cv2.flip()`
2. Numpy    `np.fliplr()`

Import the packages

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

I had a three images in a numpy array, each image with a resolution as shown here:

```
images.shape
(3, 200, 400, 3)
```

#### Using Jupyter's `%%timeit` module:

```
%%timeit -r 10 -n 100000
[cv2.flip(images[i], 1) for i in range(3)]

--> 70.4 µs ± 1.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit -r 10 -n 100000
[np.fliplr(images[i]) for i in range(3)]

--> 3.19 µs ± 288 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Running the following code ensures the results are identical:

```
x = [cv2.flip(images[i], 1) for i in range(3)]
y = [np.fliplr(images[i]) for i in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    print(np.array_equal(x[i], y[i]))

# True
# True
# True
```

So numpy is approx. 20 times faster than opencv

Comment: @scharette Yes you can answer straight away. SO is meant to help future users. If you struggled with a problem for a while and couldn't find an answer here, then figured it out yourself then you are allowed to ask a question with the intention of answering it yourself

Comment: There's a note in the Help center regarding it being OK to answer your own question at https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @scharette The question and answer obviously have to be good quality and have not been asked before. [This blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) might be of interest.