# What is the need of ellipsis[...] while modifying array values in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np                
a = np.arange(0,60,5)            
a = a.reshape(3,4)                                    

for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags = ['readwrite']):          
   x[...] = 2*x              
print 'Modified array is:'              
print a
```

In the above code, why can't we simply write x=2*x instead of x[...]=2*x?

Comment: If you write `x = 2*x` inside that loop, you just create a new variable x (different from the one that comes from the iteration) and assign the result to it. With `x[...] = 2*x`, you are modifying x directly. You might want to check [this post](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: @user2285236: `x = 2*x` doesn't create a new variable. It's just that the variable isn't the thing we need to change. Assigning to the variable doesn't help us.

Comment: What was wrong with this question that somebody downvoted it?

Comment: If you are a numpy beginner, don't spend much time on `nditer`.  Focus on whole array operations, like `b=2*a`.  Even when you must use iteration, it isn't the fastest or simplest.

Comment: The main `nditer` tutorial, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html, is most useful if you read all the way to the end, and experiment with the `cython` port.  Otherwise you'll get a false sense of its usefulness.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/42190783

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what kind of object we were iterating over or how that object was implemented, it would be almost impossible for `x = 2*x` to do anything useful to that object. `x = 2*x` is an assignment to the variable `x`; even if the previous contents of the `x` variable were obtained by iterating over some object, a new assignment to `x` would not affect the object we're iterating over.

In this specific case, iterating over a NumPy array with `np.nditer(a, op_flags = ['readwrite'])`, each iteration of the loop sets `x` to a zero-dimensional array that's a writeable *view* of a cell of `a`. `x[...] = 2*x` writes to the contents of the zero-dimensional array, rather than rebinding the `x` variable. Since the array is a view of a cell of `a`, this assignment writes to the corresponding cell of `a`.

This is very similar to the difference between `l = []` and `l[:] = []` with ordinary lists, where `l[:] = []` will clear an existing list and `l = []` will replace the list with a new, empty list without modifying the original. Lists don't support views or zero-dimensional lists, though.

Comment: The fact that `x` is 0d, and requires `x[..,]` instead of `x[:]` is part of why `nditer` is unsuitable for numpy beginners.