# AttributeError: __enter__ when using numpy nditer inside the with statement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a numpy array and change some values inside it. Here's my code, it's literally copied from the documentation ([numpy nditer docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html)):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
print(a)
with np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
  for x in it:
    x[...] = 2 * x

print(a)
```

But I keep getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text.py", line 5, in <module>
    with np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Am I doing something incorrectly, or is there a mistake in the docs (is the usage of `nditer` inside `with` deprecated)?

Comment: That probably means your numpy version is too old. `__enter__` is called by `with`, but that's not implemented in your version.

Comment: Check comments in this other recent nditer question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52135891/901925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation for Numpy 1.15, and this uses a [new feature of `nditer()` introduced in that release](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#under-certain-conditions-nditer-must-be-used-in-a-context-manager):

> **Under certain conditions, nditer must be used in a context manager**
>
> When using an `numpy.nditer` with the `"writeonly"` or `"readwrite"` flags, there are some circumstances where `nditer` doesn’t actually give you a view of the writable array. Instead, it gives you a copy, and if you make changes to the copy, `nditer` later writes those changes back into your actual array. Currently, this writeback occurs when the array objects are garbage collected, which makes this API error-prone on CPython and entirely broken on PyPy. Therefore, `nditer` should now be used as a context manager whenever it is used with writeable arrays, e.g., `with np.nditer(...) as it: ...`. You may also explicitly call `it.close()` for cases where a context manager is unusable, for instance in generator expressions.

The error indicates you have an earlier version of Numpy; the `with` statement only works with *context managers*, which [must implement `__exit__` (and `__enter__`)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers), and the `AttributeError` exception indicates that in your Numpy version the required implementation isn’t there.

Either upgrade, or don't use `with`:

```
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    x[...] = 2 * x
```

When using CPython you *may* still run into the issues that caused the change made in the 1.15 release however. When using PyPy you *will* run into those issues, and upgrading is your only proper recourse.

You probably want to refer to the [1.14 version of the same documentation entry you used](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values) (or more specifically, make sure to [pick the right documentation for your local version](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/).

Comment: Thanks, I was using numpy from Fedora's repository, which seems to be 1.14.5.  Problem solved.