# What is the meaning of a[..., 4] in python?

Tags: python, list

I am sorry if this looks easy but I can't find the meaning of this online.

Below is the original code line in the Non-max suppression function for yoloV5 in *general.py*:
 `xc = prediction[..., 4] > conf_thres #candidates`

Comment: In *Python*, it's just syntax for `prediction.__getitem__((..., 4))`. What that means to `prediction.__getitem__` is entirely dependent on the type of `prediction`.

Comment: Is `prediction` a 2D array perhaps?

Comment: [What does "three dots" in Python mean when indexing what looks like a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42190783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood it now. Below is a code snippet

```
import numpy as np
n = np.random.randint(9, size=(5,6))
print(n)
check =5
a = n[...,4]>check 

print(a)
```

Output for above code is :

```
[[1 2 2 2 4 3]
 [1 5 4 8 2 0]
 [6 6 3 0 7 6]
 [4 2 5 1 3 1]
 [3 5 2 6 4 2]]
[False False  True False False]
```