# What does this symbol mean "[...]" in docstrings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, documentation, symbols

I've seen this multiple times now in different python documents.

For example:

[image: python code]

The above is from a website that I just saw today and the rest is code written in Django. I see this symbol being regularly used in different documentations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190783/what-does-three-dots-in-python-mean-when-indexing-what-looks-like-a-number

Comment: Is it your IDE collapsing that section? Is it just a boilerplate documentation template, and it means “fill in the rest here”?

Comment: If it is the IDE then it should be clickable can you check that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "three dots" in Python mean when indexing what looks like a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190783/what-does-three-dots-in-python-mean-when-indexing-what-looks-like-a-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing particular to my knowledge.
When quoting someone, [...] is used, to mark a part of the original quote being left out.
... in shell, means navigating 3 steps to the top, folderwise.
It's not a fixed convention in python docstrings, as far as I'm aware.
https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/